# create coupon code that should apply only for new accounts

Tags: customer-account, coupon-codes

create coupon code that should apply only for new accounts.

I created a coupon code to give discounts for customers .

that coupon code is working for all customer accounts

but i want that coupon code to apply only for new customers/new accounts.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Comment: how will be you define an account is new?

Comment: you woke up early morning and trying to help others , that's great @Amit , ya new account means not registered customers.... someone who register first time ,that is new accounts.